# Dark edges and dent like artifacts when rotating a triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

When i rotate my triangle on the y axis it seems ok but when i rotate on the z axis it leaves some darker edges at the corners of the mesh and some dent like artifacts are visible near the corners. I can't understand why. I think the math for the rotations are correct.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dep/GLEW/glew.h"
#include "dep/GLFW/glfw3.h"

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void character_callback(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int codepoint);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);


int main()
{

    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow *window;
    //window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "der", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
    window=glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "der", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    float positions[9] =
    { -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };
        unsigned int indices[] = { 0,1,2 };
        unsigned int myvertexarrayobject;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &myvertexarrayobject);
        glBindVertexArray(myvertexarrayobject);

        unsigned int myvertexbufferobject;
        glGenBuffers(1, &myvertexbufferobject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myvertexbufferobject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        unsigned int ebo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        const char* vertex_shader =
            "#version 440 core\n"
            "in vec3 vp;"
            "uniform vec4 qtr;"
            "vec4 pt=vec4(vp,1.0);"
            "vec4 npt=vec4(-qtr[0],-qtr[1],-qtr[2],qtr[3]);"
            "vec4 sqtr=vec4((qtr[3]*pt[0]+qtr[0]*pt[3]+qtr[1]*pt[2]-qtr[2]*pt[1]),(qtr[3]*pt[1]-qtr[0]*pt[2]+qtr[1]*pt[3]+qtr[2]*pt[0]),(qtr[3]*pt[2]+qtr[0]*pt[1]-qtr[1]*pt[0]+qtr[2]*pt[3]),(qtr[3]*pt[3]-qtr[0]*pt[0]-qtr[1]*pt[1]-qtr[2]*pt[2]));"
            "vec4 npoint=vec4((sqtr[3]*npt[0]+sqtr[0]*npt[3]+sqtr[1]*npt[2]-sqtr[2]*npt[1]),(sqtr[3]*npt[1]-sqtr[0]*npt[2]+sqtr[1]*npt[3]+sqtr[2]*npt[0]),(sqtr[3]*npt[2]+sqtr[0]*npt[1]-sqtr[1]*npt[0]+sqtr[2]*npt[3]),(sqtr[3]*npt[3]-sqtr[0]*npt[0]-sqtr[1]*npt[1]-sqtr[2]*npt[2]));"
            "void main() {"
            "  gl_Position =npoint;"
            "}";
        const char* fragment_shader =
            "#version 440 core\n"
            "out vec4 frag_colour;"
            "void main() {"
            "  frag_colour = vec4(0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);"
            "}";

        GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vs);
        GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fs);

        GLuint shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shader_programme, fs);
        glAttachShader(shader_programme, vs);
        glLinkProgram(shader_programme);
        glDeleteShader(vs);
        glDeleteShader(fs);


        int countt = 0;
        float i = 0.0f;
        float ki(sin((i / 2)));
        float kj(0.0f);
        float kl(cos((i / 2)));
        
        std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
        std::cout << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
        std::cout << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
        std::cout << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            if (countt < 180 && countt >= 0)
            {
                i = i + 0.1f;
                ki = sin(i / 2);
                kl = cos(i / 2);
                countt++;
            }
            else if (countt >= 180 && countt < 360)
            {
                i = i - 0.1f;
                ki = sin(i / 2);
                kl = cos(i / 2);
                countt++;
            }
            else
            {

                countt = 0;
            }
            int widt;
            int hei;
            glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &widt, &hei);
            glViewport(0, 0, widt, hei);
            glfwSetCharCallback(window, character_callback);
            processInput(window);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

            glUseProgram(shader_programme);

            glBindVertexArray(myvertexarrayobject);
            GLuint transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_programme, "qtr");

            glUniform4f(transformLoc, kj, kj, ki, kl);
            
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

            //swap front and back buffers
            
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            //poll for and procces events
            glfwPollEvents();

        }

    glfwTerminate();
    
    return 0;
}


void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }

}

void character_callback(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int codepoint)
{
    std::cout << (char)codepoint << std::endl;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: No because the printscreen does not show what i am describing. It seems ok in the printscreen, but when the program is running the artifacts are visible

Comment: error: ‘sin’ was not declared in this scope, error: ‘cos’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Looks fine to me on Linux: AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 11 Graphics (RAVEN, DRM 3.37.0, 5.7.0-0.bpo.2-amd64, LLVM 11.0.1)

Comment: I don't get an error on sin and cos.Maybe #include <math.h>. I checked with c++17 and c++14 with no error, but i don't really know. Doesn't it leave darker traces on the edges of the triangle and some small dents or am i going mad? Darker than the color i specified on the fragment shader, also it seems like you can almost see 2 triangles